# How do I resize the screen on my LCD touchscreen?

Tags: screen, touchscreen

I would like to resize the screen of my Raspberry Pi with a 3.2" LCD, because is too small to view easily. How can I resize the screen?

Comment: Please specify exactly which touchscreen module you own.

Comment: I have a 3.2" lcd but it work only one specific OS, and if i would like to Ise this lcd on kali Linux, it don't work

Comment: What's the type of that lcd? There are a couple of 3.2" lcd out there which are very different from each other.

Comment: https://banggood.app.link/jQN8XJiOTx, i bought it from banggod

Comment: Thats the *RPI TFT 32*. It's connected via SPI, so you need a custom kernel image where the FBTFT driver is compiled in. What's that "resize a screen" question is about? Are you looking for another FBTFT compatible display which is bigger? Why don't you use a HDMI display with touch when you need a bigger display?

Comment: Because i would like to take out whit a powerbank and a mini display

Comment: Please look at the displays Adafruit offers https://www.adafruit.com/category/63. There are a lot of options, using either HDMI or the special Raspberry Pi display connector. Connecting a display to the SPI port is somewhat outdated and I think the 3.2" variant is the last one which made it to the market.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on PPI and resolution, this may not be possible without making things unable to be seen or read. I don't have that screen personally, but I have the Official 7" touch screen, and that can't be resized.